# Event 1202 when trying to run a scheduled task GPO under NT Authority\System

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to get a barcode font installed on machines for a enterprise application. The GPO is being served from a Windows Server 2019 Standard version 1809 OS build 17763.4252 server. The GPO in question uses computer preferences -> Scheduled Tasks to immediately run a script. Shown below.

```
#$fonts = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace(0x14)
$Path = Test-Path \\DC\netlogon\font\
if($Path -eq $true)
{
Write-EventLog -Source Application -LogName Application -EventId 301 -EntryType Information -Message "The Network Path is True" 
$fontFolder = "\\DC\NETLOGON\Font\ "
$fontItem = Get-Item -Path $fontFolder
$fontList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fontItem\*" -Include ('*.fon','*.otf','*.ttc','*.ttf')
$RegPath =(Test-Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts')
$objFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection

}
foreach ($font in $fontList) 
    {
     $objFont.AddFontFile($font.FullName)
     $objTitle = $objFont.Families[-1].Name 
     $fontName = $font.Name
     $objExtension = switch ($font.Extension)
        {
            .TTF {"(True Type Font)"}
            .OTF {"(Open Type Font)"}
            Default {
            Write-EventLog -Source Application -LogName Application -EventId 305 -EntryType Information -Message "Font Extension not Found"
            }
         }  
     $FontTitle = $objTitle + " " + $objExtension
     if (-not(Test-Path -Path "C:\Windows\fonts\$fontName" )) {
        Write-EventLog -Source Application -LogName Application -EventId 302 -EntryType Information -Message "Font not Found, Installing font."
        echo $fontName

        reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v $FontTitle /t REG_SZ /d DWBAR39.TTF /f
        cp $font C:\Windows\Fonts 
        
        if (Test-Path -Path "C:\windows\fonts\$fontName")
            {
            Write-EventLog -Source Application -LogName Application -EventId 306 -EntryType Information -Message "Font Installed."
         }   
        
    }
    
    elseif (Test-Path -Path "C:\Windows\fonts\$fontName"){
    Write-EventLog -Source Application -LogName Application -EventId 303 -EntryType Information -Message "Font Already Installed in C:\windows\fonts\"
    }
   }
```

The Script works well locally. I can run it and it works no problem. Whenever I refresh the group policy, I get Event 1202,SceCLI

> 0x5 : Access is denied. Advanced help for this problem is available on
> https://support.microsoft.com. Query for "troubleshooting 1202
> events".

Currently it's running as so in the GPO.

> Name  C - Font Installer
> Author  'Me'
> Description  Installs fonts.
> Run only when user is logged on  S4U
> UserId  NT AUTHORITY\System
> Run with highest privileges  HighestAvailable
> Hidden  Yes
> Configure for 1.2
> Enabled  Yes
>
> Program/script
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> Arguments  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '&
> \DC\netlogon\add-Font.ps1'     Start in
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell
>
> Stop if the computer ceases to be idle  Yes
> Restart if the idle state resumes  No
> Start the task only if the computer is on AC power  Yes
> Stop if the computer switches to battery power  No
> Allow task to be run on demand  Yes
> Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed  Yes
> Stop task if it runs longer than  3 days force it to stop  Yes
> If the running task does not end when requested,
> If the task is not scheduled to run again, delete it after  Immediately
> If the task is already running, then the following rule applies  StopExisting

Going down the Permissions angle. I found by using PSEXEC64.exe -sid powershell. And running out the dir $font | %{$fonts.CopyHere($_.FullName)} There isn't any output.

This site https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=16137 Helps with why that may be. Seems the 0x14 shell variable is being overloaded and redirects to the user profile. Which I've seen happen when I ran the script locally.

*After additions to the script I still get the SceCLI errors, It doesn't appear the script even runs, because I do not get any of the event logging that I added. How/Why? I'm using the SYSTEM account to perform these actions.

I disabled windows firewall for domain scope, and now I no longer receive the SceCLI error. Still nothing applies.

Any help at all would be amazing.

thank you.

Comment: You need to add logging to your script so that it will record where the error occurs.

Comment: It's not the script. I've isolated the cause by also disabling the script and trying again via this method https://4sysops.com/archives/install-fonts-in-windows-10-or-windows-11-with-group-policy/ Creating a registry and copying the fonts. I still get the SceCLI message and now I get a The computer 'Fonts' preference item in the 'C - Font Installer {592B0841-56DD-4D91-80DD-CBEF90ED4218}' Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070005 Access is denied.' This error was suppressed. Event 4098, Group Policy Files

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with the script. Powershell ISE interpreted everything properly but when processed as a GPO it was not. The Line

```
$fontFolder = "\\DC\NETLOGON\Font\"
```

Broke the quotations because the \ acted as an ignore character. After I took that backslash away it started working properly.
@GregAskew You can say I told you so.

Thanks,
WC.